# Install ubuntu on mac

Tags: ubuntu, mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install ubuntu on MacBook Pro](https://superuser.com/questions/39939/install-ubuntu-on-macbook-pro)

I have an old mac (maybe 6 years old) that I want to install Ubuntu on. I have an Ubuntu live cd but when I but it in the cd drive and hold down the the option key when rebooting, the cd is not listed in the boot menu.

The mac came from a company that was getting new computers so I have the feeling that it was some how protected from doing this.

Any idea of what I can do to install Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you tried holding down the 'c' key during reboot to try to start up from the CD drive?

Comment: Also, what did you do to burn the CD? Did you burn it to the CD with Disk Utility, or did you just copy the contents of the ISO over to the CD?

Comment: Holding down the "C" key does nothing. I used the CD on other systems that previously had Windows on them and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

If your Mac is six years old, then it's a PowerPC Mac with a G4 or G5 CPU, and you'll need the version of Ubuntu for the PowerPC CPU architecture. What CPU architecture does your Live CD support? I believe the standard Ubuntu Live CD only supports Intel-compatible architectures.

Comment: Where can I get a PowerPC compatible Ubuntu CD?

Comment: Correct, the standard LiveCD is i386 only.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has PPC builds, you can grab it [**here**](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ports/releases/10.10/release/) on the ports page. This pertains to G3, G4 and G5 machines alike. If you have an Intel Mac, you can use the regular Intel i386 build. You can find out what kind of Mac you have with the [**"About this Mac"**](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1633) utility.